# Child of circular container is visible behind containers border

Tags: flutter

I have an image inside a container as an profile picture but image is a little bit visible behind the border of the container as you can see in the provided image. Is there any fix to this?

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.grey[800]),
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 8, spreadRadius: 3, color: Colors.black26)],
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiJEu.png

Comment: What does this line means: `image is a little bit visible behind the border of the container as you can see in the provided image`? Not very clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

See if changing fit to `fit: BoxFit.contain,` fixes your problem and if it doesn't can you please exactly explain where it is visible because I don't see it in the picture you provided unless you are talking about the part at the very top of the picture.